# Why wordpress multisite redirect to wp-signup if site exists?

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, ssl, wp-signup

I just create a site on my Multisite domain (example.com), for instance site1.example.com

After this, I try to enter on https://site1.example.com/wp-admin, but I'm redirected to https://www.example.com/wp-signup.php?new=example.com

My .htaccess containt this lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I have installed, among others, this plugins

- wordfence Security
- Loginizer
- WP Maintenance Mode (with Status Activated)

Why wordpress multisite redirect me to wp-signup if the site already exists?

The problem is because de SSL certificate, because I tried enter by HTTP and It's ok

How can solve it? Can I change something on .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess file looks like it is for a network that uses sub-folders but the URL address that you say you are trying is for a network that uses sub-domains. Which type are you using? Have you followed the steps in the /wp-admin/network/setup.php page correctly?

Another idea is that you have added SSL but the site is maybe still using the old http URL addresses. Click edit on one of the sites to see the Site Address (URL) field. Does it have https there or just http?

Answer (score -1):

The redirect is to the main WordPress site and this is the way WordPress Multisite works.  The sign up is always on the main site of the Network/Multisite.

if you want to allow registration on a subsite only try https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/